# Implementing Geometry Columns in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, postgresql

The geometry_columns in **postgres** looks like (question in [gis.stackexchange](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/71558/implementing-geometry-columns-table-in-sql-server-for-qgis)) :

```
SELECT 
    current_database()::character varying(256) AS f_table_catalog, 
    n.nspname::character varying(256) AS f_table_schema, 
    c.relname::character varying(256) AS f_table_name, 
    a.attname::character varying(256) AS f_geometry_column, 
    COALESCE(NULLIF(postgis_typmod_dims(a.atttypmod), 2),postgis_constraint_dims(n.nspname::text, c.relname::text, a.attname::text), 2) AS coord_dimension, 
    COALESCE(NULLIF(postgis_typmod_srid(a.atttypmod), 0), postgis_constraint_srid(n.nspname::text, c.relname::text, a.attname::text), 0) AS srid, 
    replace(replace(COALESCE(NULLIF(upper(postgis_typmod_type(a.atttypmod)), 'GEOMETRY'::text), postgis_constraint_type(n.nspname::text, c.relname::text, a.attname::text)::text, 'GEOMETRY'::text), 'ZM'::text, ''::text), 'Z'::text, ''::text)::character varying(30) AS type
FROM 
    pg_class c, pg_attribute a, pg_type t, pg_namespace n
WHERE 
    t.typname = 'geometry'::name 
    AND a.attisdropped = false 
    AND a.atttypid = t.oid 
    AND a.attrelid = c.oid 
    AND c.relnamespace = n.oid 
    AND (c.relkind = 'r'::"char" OR c.relkind = 'v'::"char") 
    AND NOT pg_is_other_temp_schema(c.relnamespace) 
    AND NOT (n.nspname = 'public'::name AND c.relname = 'raster_columns'::name) 
    AND has_table_privilege(c.oid, 'SELECT'::text);
```

The alternative that I am making for SQL Server is:

```
SELECT  
    c.TABLE_CATALOG
    ,c.TABLE_SCHEMA AS TABLE_SCHEMA
    ,c.TABLE_NAME AS TABLE_NAME
    ,c.COLUMN_NAME AS COLUMN_NAME   
FROM 
    information_schema.columns c
JOIN 
    information_schema.tables t ON c.TABLE_NAME = t.TABLE_NAME
                                AND t.TABLE_TYPE IN ('BASE TABLE','VIEW')
                                AND t.TABLE_SCHEMA = c.TABLE_SCHEMA
WHERE 
    c.DATA_TYPE = 'geometry'
```

*But it doesn't have:*

- **coord_dimension**
- **srid**
- **type**

I know the query in SQL Server to get value listed above is :

```
SELECT distinct 
    @column_name.STDimension() as coord_dimension ,
    SP_GEOMETRY.STGeometryType() as srid,
    SP_GEOMETRY.STSrid 
FROM
    schema_name.@table_name
```

This query needs to query through table to find distinct `STDimension` since single table can have multiple dimensions.

**How do I combine this two query into a single query as in postgres?**

Note: I want use to view only table that they have access to and I think querying `Information_schema` will be enough for it. Am I correct?

Answer (score 1):

I can't speak to postgres' implementation, but those properties are not properties of the column itself in SQL Server. That is, the column doesn't have an SRID, but the individual data within it do. You could, in theory, have two rows each with their geography data in a different SRID (for instance). The same goes for dimension and geometry type. So what you're looking for isn't available as a metadata lookup on the table schema; you'll have to look at the data itself.

Comment: @column_name.STDimension() as coord_dimension ,
    SP_GEOMETRY.STGeometryType() as srid,
    SP_GEOMETRY.STSrid  is what I did for extracting column property. Any Idea How that can be mashed with above query?

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish? If you have a table with 10 rows in it (for instance), just call the above methods on the column names. So "select col.STDimension() from your_table" would give you 10 rows back, each row being a one column result with the dimension for that row.

Comment: Actually I am trying to get it all in one query. I need STDimension in the same query as I the query on information schema. Do I need to loop into all spatial tables and query into each column names or do I have any alternative?

Comment: That's what I'm saying: the column itself doesn't have a dimension; the data within the column do. Back to my example of a table with 10 rows with one geospatial index, one row might contain a linestring while another might contain a polygon. So, querying the metadata to ask "what is the dimension of this column?" doesn't make sense. It'd be like asking the metadata "how big are the values in this int column?". Absent an explicit constraint, you need to interrogate the actual data (as opposed to the metadata) to answer that question.